# Is there a link format for physical street address?

Tags: html, mobile, hyperlink

Mobile devices have started to do link detection fairly well. They now detect links, email address, phone numbers and physical street addresses.

The problem is that link detection is not 100% correct. So to be more explicit, for most of these, we can use a link.

```
<a href="tel:+1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

Is there an equivalent link format for a physical street address?

Comment: What transport protocol would you use for an address? `walk:`? `drive:`? :)

Comment: physical address? as in the geography address?

Comment: @sarnold well these might not even be in the same country. i just want the device to bring up the map to the address

Comment: @Jasonw physical street address. so yes "geography address". update question

Comment: @Simon not sure about geography address (probably different country has different address format), but [geo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) may come close to achieve what you want.

Comment: let's make it <a snail:"123 Street, city, country, zip" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be one defined, [according to the IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html). Here is a [discussion](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2001Mar/0012.html) about creating one, but it doesn't seem it ever went anywhere. The closest I can find is [geo](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5870.txt), which is just latitude and longitude, not a postal address. I see from the update that you want to display a map, so what you want is to [geocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) the address to get a geo URI. You could use [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) but I don't know if there is any need for the geo URI at that point.